# Boolean class object in Freemarker

Tags: java, boolean, freemarker

In FreeMarker, i am passing a variable having type 'Boolean' but in ftl the variable does not evaluate to true or false, but if pass variable as 'boolean' it works as expected. Is there any way to use Boolean Object variable in ftl.

Comment: Should work by default according to https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html So you need to show code/configuration

Answer (score 2):

`Boolean` is of course supported by FreeMarker. The typical problem is that the `Boolean` object is exposed through a method like `public Boolean isSomething()`, instead of `public Boolean getSomething()`. According the Java Beans rules (which aren't defined by FreeMarker), you can only use an "is" read-method for `boolean` properties, not for `Boolean` properties.